# jquery css with dynamically created element not working

Tags: jquery

I'm creating an element using jquery then appending it to another one. I'm trying to style my header but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason. There doesn't seem to be any syntax errors. It's appending to the div and the text is appearing, it's just not being styled.

```
 jQuery('<h3/>', {

text: 'Todays news',
css: ('background-color', 'red'),
id: 'tdn'

}).appendTo('#div1');
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your CSS style inside `{ }` instead of `( )`

```
jQuery('<h3/>', {
    text: 'Todays news',
    id: 'tdn',
    css: {'background-color': 'red'},
}).appendTo('#div1');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3pUSz/)**

or you can use **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** as well:

```
jQuery('<h3/>', {
    text: 'Todays news',
    id: 'tdn'
}).css('background-color', 'red').appendTo('#div1');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f3f3Z/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using {} instead of () for your css parameters

```
$('<h3/>', {

text: 'Todays news',
    css: {'background-color': 'red'},
id: 'tdn'

}).appendTo('#div1');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xerxesnoble/e93Hj/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
jQuery('<h3/>', {
    text: 'Todays news',
    id: 'tdn'
    style: 'background-color:red'
}).appendTo('#div1');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3f3Z/1/)

Answer (score 1):

use `style:` instead of `css:`

```
 jQuery('<h3/>', {

text: 'Todays news',
style: "background-color:red",
id: 'tdn'

}).appendTo('#div1');
```